# Bug when trying to login to Api Laravel using React

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8

When I trying to login I have this error"

```
message "Target class [App\\http\\Middleware\\ApiLogin] does not exist."
```

When I use localhost I'dont have this error.

Please help

Comment: Your middleware doesn't exist in the project. If you're working on Laravel 8.x then it should be under `app > http > Middlewares` You can create a new middleware by using `php artisan make:middleware <yourmiddlewarename>`

Comment: I have file ApiLogin.php in Middleware folder

Comment: have you created the file manually or using artisan command?

Comment: add the ApiLogin namespace wherever you're importing it: "use App\Middleware\ApiLogin;". Must have the correct source typed